# how to get value of this ul list

Tags: ajax, list, jquery

The code is this:

```
<ins>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ins>&nbsp;</ins>
        <ul id="eventselect">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Birthdays">Birthdays</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Graduation">Graduation</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Wedding">Wedding</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Farewell">Farewell</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Party">Party</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Bbq">Bbq</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Party">Party</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Warming_party">Housewarming</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Christmas">Christmas</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" rel="Other">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ins>
```

I have tried following code for to access the value:

```
$("#eventselect").val();
$("#eventselect :selected").text();
```

But nothing worked, now my question is how to get the value of this please.

## EDIT - 1

Hi guys,
sorry, I realized that i shouldnt have used this $("#eventselect :selected").text(); . There is a problem which I am getting the list starts with an empty select box, which I think comes from that `<ins>&nbsp;</ins>`, and if I remove that I am not getting anything in the list. And with that tag inside I can access the value or text by using `$("#eventselect li").text();`. But the value is birthdays even when the blank first li is there. How to rectify it?

Comment: You can only access val() on elements that have the value attribute.

Comment: What value are you trying to get? I think you are confusing <select> tags with <ul> list tags

Comment: This isn't a form element, so it doesn't have a `.val()`. Is this part of some plugin? How are the list elements selected?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `#eventselect` is a list, it doesn't have a value.

Comment: Try out my last solution, with the click event on the A element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way of accessing the "selected value" of an UL its if you can distinct one from the others, maybe with a class. Let's say the selected one get to have the `selected` class on the LI element. Then you could access it like this:

```
$('#eventselect li.selected a').text();
```

or maybe if you want the `rel` attribute:

```
$('#eventselect li.selected a').attr('rel');
```

Where one way of distinct the selected one from the others it's doing something like this:

```
$('#eventselect li a').click(function(){
    $('#eventselect li').removeClass('selected'); // remove all selected class values
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected'); // add class selected to selected value
});
```

You can get the selected value with the click event too, like this:

```
$('#eventselect li a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('ref'); // Get the ref attribute from the "a" element
});
```

Comment: ..thanks for the answer, i am having a blank line between the list. An empty blank line.. thats from INS tag..please look at my edit.

Comment: Hm, seems you are using a jquery plugin or something, can you pass me the javascript tags from your html?

Comment: The value it's always Birthdays because with that "jquery selector" he brings the first on your list and not the selected one. Your list doesnt have selected value because its a list not a select element.